# intersection of 2 string files - java

Tags: java, string, intersection

I have 2 files with string lines, and I have to find the number of lines that belongs to both of the files.

how can I do it?

for example - 
file1:

```
aaa 
bbb
ccc
```

file2:

```
bbb
eee
aaa
```

Result should be 2

Comment: Run over the first file, put all lines in a list. Then run through the second file and use the contains function

Comment: @GroundZero A `Set` will perform *significantly* better if the files have anything more than a 100 lines.

Comment: Doesn't matter what he uses to save the lines in. I was mainly referring to the contains-function when running over the 2nd file to count

Comment: With due respect, it *does* matter what is used to contain the lines. For 1000-line files, it matters at least by a factor of 200.

Answer (score 2):

You read all lines from file1 into a `Set` and then check if it already contains the ones from file2:

```
 Set<String> linesFile1 = ... read in your lines
 for (String line : file2) {  // add each line from file2 and check if it was already in the set
    if (linesFile1.contains(line)) {
         counter++;
    }
 }
```

Comment: Why add() instead of contains() ? IF he uses add() and if there is duplicate line in FILE2, IMHO it will give incorrect result.

Comment: you're right! i fix it ;-)

Comment: can you please explain me this line: Set<String> linesFile1 = ... read in your lines

Comment: I mean you read in all lines from your first file and put it into a `Set`.

Comment: why `!linesFile1.contains(line)`? shouldn't it be `linesFile1.contains(line)`? In intersection we are considering the common elements, aren't we?

Comment: yes sorry, I had before `add` there, and forgot to change

Answer (score 0):

Use `retainAll(..)` operation for intersection,

```
 Set<String> aSet=new HashSet(Arrays.asList("aaa", "bbb", "ccc"));
 Set<String> bSet=new HashSet(Arrays.asList( "bbb", "eee","aaa"));

 aSet.retainAll(bSet);//This will do the intersection operation between two Set

 System.out.println(aSet.size());
```

Comment: It is much more efficent to have a set of just the first file.

Answer (score 0):

Basic algorithm

```
1. Read all lines from file1 and add it into Set1
2. Read all lines from file2 and add it into Set2
3. Then use Guava's intersection method to obtain a new intersection Set
4. Print out the size of the intersection set.
```

[Guava's intersection method](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Sets.html#intersection%28java.util.Set,%20java.util.Set%29).